# issue with vscode jupyter notebook editor

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My issue is similar to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14359

1. create a new blank notebook
2. export as python script
   Export would fail with
   KeyError: 'template_paths'

Is this really a bug or I am not setting up some path properly?
Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3499.

Comment: You need to give your prob in a clear way not a similar way